# ClassNotFoundException with JGroups

Tags: java, classpath, jgroups

I have an issue with JGroups where after building my project, running it produces this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jgroups.ReceiverAdapter`

My class looks something like this -

```
import org.jgroups.ReceiverAdapter;
import org.jgroups.Channel;
import org.jgroups.JChannel;

public class MyClass extends ReceiverAdapter implements MyInterface {

    Channel channel;
    String state = "state";

    public MyClass() {
        super();
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            channel = new JChannel();
            channel.setReceiver(this);
            channel.connect("ServerCluster");
            channel.getState(null, 0);
            System.out.println("Connected to cluster");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to cluster");
        }
    }

    public void getState(OutputStream output) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("get response");
    }

    public void setState(InputStream input) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("set test");
    }
}
```

Running the project from IntelliJ produces no errors, but does not produce the desired prints from `getState()` and `setState()` either. I tried creating a brand new project in the Eclipse IDE, but the same is happening there too. Connecting has been working fine, states is a new addition to my project.

Running `java MyClass` from the command line fires the error seen at the start of this question.  The JGroups jar seems to be added to the classpath properly as `org.jgroups.Channel` and `org.jgroups.Channel` (among others) are being found.

There is a [SimpleChat](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/code/SimpleChat.java) program provided by the JGroup devs, but when I created a new project for this I encountered the same problem.

**Edit**

So it turns out I have to explicitly set the classpath when running from the CLI. But still, when running the code it seems like the `getState()` and `setState()` methods are never called as there are no print statements. `SimpleChat` doesn't print `received state...` like it is meant to.

Does anyone have a solution?

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I on the JChannel I was using RpcDispatcher and it seems I can't use the dispatcher and the `getState()` and `setState()` methods on the same channel. Simple solution: create a second channel. Seems my knowledge on the fundamentals of JGroups is lacking!